# Multiple data flows for 1000+ tables ssis

Tags: ssis, package, dataflowtask

Hi I have created a ssis package which loads source to target table and for each table I have to create a data flow, duplicate, rinse and repeat. It’ll take quite a bit of time to do 1000 tables and I was wondering if there was a faster way to created these data flows?

Comment: You need more detail on what/how the tables are?  Are they all the same name in source/destination?  Should be pretty easy with C# script task.   If not then still C# Script task can do whatever SSIS can not do out of the box.  Though you need more details to get help.   https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automating SSIS package creation is embarrassingly easy with Biml (Business Intelligence Markup Language).

1. Install the free (registration required) [BimlExpress](https://varigence.com/bimlexpress)
2. Create 1 package as "normal" and then right click and use the Reverse Engineer option to have BimlExpress create the raw Biml that describes the package you built
3. Automate the pattern however it makes sense.

[BimlScript](https://bimlscript.com) is a free, community oriented patterns and learning site. It has an excellent learning tutorial on the matter

- Cathrine Wilhelmsen has great [resources](https://www.cathrinewilhelmsen.net/search/?q=biml)
- [Stairway to Biml](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/steps/stairway-to-biml-level-1-what-is-biml) is an excellent series by Andy Leonard
- [Replicate-o-Matic](https://billfellows.blogspot.com/2015/01/biml-replicate-o-matic.html) is a short example of how I can use a query to make the the #3 "automate" the pattern. It queries all the tables in a database and creates a package per table with a basic table source to table destination.

The final bit of advice I'd offer is: do not make 1 package with 1000+ data flows in it. Every time you go to open the package, run it, etc, you will spend a long time validating the metadata of each and every source and sink.

Instead, create a package per entity to transfer (worker) and then create an Orchestrator package that runs the workers. The orchestrator can be as simple as hard coding every package in serial or something more interesting like a table of packages to be run, when they were last run and dynamically invokes them based on expected run time with N workers running in parallel.

Comment: I was looking at BimlExpress and noticed it hasn't been updated in 5 years, and only offers support up to VS 2019/SSIS 2019. This is concerning to me, as it looks like the product may have been abandoned. Any insights on that?

Comment: @JakeMunson Behind-the-scenes knowledge: None. Reading of tea leaves: Microsoft isn't putting any effort into SSIS. It's not listed as deprecated or anything severe like that but there are no engineering dollars being spent on new features, purely life support. That said, SSIS is going to be around for at least 3 versions given how deprecation cycles work at MS so minimum 6 years given the current release cadence. But you can look at products like ...Comet?, the visual table designer in SSMS. That's been there since 2000 & doesn't support all the current table features, but it still works-ish.

Comment: Varigence, the folks that product BimlExpress give that away to entice people to try and buy their really good products: BimlStudio and BimlFlex. Those products are kept current with annual releases. With yet-another-means of installing the SSIS tools with the 2022 release of VS (which was different from 2012-2019, which was different from 2005-2010) I'm _guessing_ it'll take awhile to prioritize that loss leader development work. But they're good peeps so I suspect there will be a 2022+ compatible release but no idea of when that might be.

Comment: As a consultant with a bunch of years under my belt, if the choice was to create new SSIS packages (on prem/vm servers, sources and sinks meet the business needs, etc), I would absolutely continue to use Biml to define my patterns and emit those into SSIS packages (and beyond). The real juice for Biml is the integrated metadata driven development but it's the hardest thing to "sell." Identify the source of your metadata - information schema tables, Excel spreadsheets, whatever and then apply those to your Biml patterns (this is a type 1, this is a type 2) and whoosh, out come data warehouses.

Comment: Great insights @billinkc, thanks. I have also believed that MS has SSIS/SSAS on life support and have for years. Where I work, we still have a lot of investment in these two so we won't be moving away anytime soon.

As far as Biml, I agree. Again, great insights.